# Exception thrown when starting Elastic search with X-pack

Tags: elasticsearch, xpack

I have elasticsearch 5.2.0 with x-pack. I am in OS X Sierra and I downloaded the binaries from the official [website](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch)

An exception shows up everytime I try to start `elasticsearch`. The Warning shown is the following:

```
[2017-02-25T11:30:06,354][WARN ][o.e.d.z.UnicastZenPing   ] [k9ErfRE] [1] failed send ping to {#zen_unicast_127.0.0.1_0#}{Xruys5FnTRaRKgOnhThjEg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: handshake failed with {#zen_unicast_127.0.0.1_0#}{Xruys5FnTRaRKgOnhThjEg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.handshake(TransportService.java:364) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.UnicastZenPing$PingingRound.getOrConnect(UnicastZenPing.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.UnicastZenPing$3.doRun(UnicastZenPing.java:500) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:596) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [Dc1gCWm][127.0.0.1:9300][internal:transport/handshake]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: missing authentication token for action [internal:transport/handshake]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.support.Exceptions.authenticationError(Exceptions.java:39) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.missingToken(DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:74) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$AuditableTransportRequest.anonymousAccessDenied(AuthenticationService.java:483) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$handleNullToken$13(AuthenticationService.java:315) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.handleNullToken(AuthenticationService.java:320) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.consumeToken(AuthenticationService.java:247) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$extractToken$5(AuthenticationService.java:223) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.extractToken(AuthenticationService.java:236) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$authenticateAsync$0(AuthenticationService.java:184) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$lookForExistingAuthentication$2(AuthenticationService.java:201) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lookForExistingAuthentication(AuthenticationService.java:213) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.authenticateAsync(AuthenticationService.java:180) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.access$000(AuthenticationService.java:142) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService.authenticate(AuthenticationService.java:114) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.ServerTransportFilter$NodeProfile.inbound(ServerTransportFilter.java:142) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler.messageReceived(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:296) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$RequestHandler.doRun(TcpTransport.java:1488) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsExecutors$1.execute(EsExecutors.java:109) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.handleRequest(TcpTransport.java:1445) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1329) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:280) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:396) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:642) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:527) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[?:?]
```

Do you know what is it and why does it appear and how to make it stop?
N.B.: Elasticsearch correctly start after this warning, and everything seems to work fine (for example in querying it or adding indexes and elements to them), but it bothers me that warning and I am afraid that it is a sign for something worse. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue with Zen Discovery. Maybe you should increase the ping timeout. More info here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html

Comment: why does it work without it? I mean after going in timeout, why it still opens elasticsearch correctly? 
And why does it need Zen Discovery?

Comment: It works without it because once everything is up an running, it works fine. The problem is just that all the modules are not up within the initial timeout and that's when the error is thrown.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it, but I think you can get rid of the error by increasing the timeout - it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must read the latest documentation from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/installing-xpack.html#installing-xpack

To use X-Pack you need:

Elasticsearch 5.3.0 - Installing Elasticsearch

Kibana 5.3.0 - Getting Kibana Up and Running

after all installed on u're machine

let's surf this documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-getting-started.html